# Can p-value really never be 0?

Tags: t-test, p-value

I've been told by professors that the Gaussian distribution asymptotes but never reaches 0 and thus the p-value can never be 0, but this doesn't make sense to me.

To put it in simple practical terms, say you are sampling a population of 100 people's responses to a 7-point Likert scale. You want to see if this population differs from another population who's known mean is 2. You pull a sample of 90 people and their mean is 7. Even if all 10 remaining people in the population that did not make it into your sample have a score of 1 (lowest possible score), the population mean would still be greater than 2. There is 0% chance of the effect you found being due to random sampling error thus, the p-value of this test should be 0 right??

Comment: You pulled a quick one in this question: in the situation you posit, nothing can possibly be Normally distributed. The distributions of any possible test statistics are finite and discrete. If you use a Normal approximation, then that approximation will always produce a positive p-value. But if you use a more accurate calculation, it could produce a zero p-value. Those two conclusions aren't at odds with one another, because "p-value" refers to two subtly different quantities in the two cases. You might as well ask "how is it possible for an approximation to zero not to actually equal zero?"

Comment: Whuber, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that because the t-test is based on an approximation to the data and not the actual data, that is why the p-value would not be 0 even though in this case there is zero probability of a type I error?

Comment: The t-test explicitly is based on the data--no approximation is made there.  The use of the Student $t$ distribution is where the approximation happens: the $t$ statistic does not actually have that distribution.

Comment: To add to @whuber's comment, a p-value of zero would mean having a surface area under a curve that would be equal to zero. The only mathematical object that has an area of zero is a point - but the definition of a point is an axiom that has no parallel in the real world.

Comment: @Digio Plenty of geometric objects in the plane have zero areas besides points.  A relevant example would be the area under the graph of the PDF of the Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: There is another example of a test giving p-value=0 (and p-value=1) in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280846/p-value-equal-to-1-in-permutation-proportion-test-while-prop-test-and-binom-test . It's a binomial test with null hypothesis $p=0$. On the other hand, in the t-test the p-value can never be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion appears to stem from a misinterpretation of what the p-value is.

**What a p-value is *not*:**
A p-value is not the probability that a certain statistic in your sample is equal to a specific value, given what you know about a sub-sample of that sample. This appears to be what you believe the p-value is telling you. Namely, the probability that the mean response of your second sample of 100 is equal to 2, given that you know that a sub-sample of 90 of those participants has a mean response of 7.

**What a p-value is:**
It's the probability that the statistic you're trying to measure in your sample would fall within a specified range, given that the distribution from which you're sampling is a certain specified distribution (i.e. the "null hypothesis").

Suppose, for example, that you adopt the following probability distribution of a response on your Likert-scale question as your null hypothesis:

$p(1) = 5/12$

$p(2) = 1/2$

$p(3) = 0$

$p(4) = 0$

$p(5) = 0$

$p(6) = 0$

$p(7) = 1/12$

This distribution has an expected value of 2. (Note, this is probably not a novel null hypothesis to adopt, I'm just taking it as an example.) Then, as you can probably tell, the probability of getting 90 consecutive "7" answers is not zero, it's $(1/12)^{90} \approx 7 \times 10^{-98}.$ This would be your "p-value", i.e. the probability that a distribution given by the null hypothesis can produce the observed result of 90 participants answering "7".

Keep in mind that the above example is pretty contrived, but it was helpful for illustration. It's easy to use the distribution above to calculate the probability of all 7s. However, because I forced the probability of getting, say, an answer of "4" to zero, this implies that the probability of getting all "4"s is again zero. That's *not* the same as asking the probability of getting a mean response of 4, which is not zero. (For example, two "seven" responses and two "one" responses has a mean result of "four".) Because of this, it could still be appropriate to use the Central Limit Theorem, that is, approximate the distribution of the mean response as a Gaussian for a large enough sample size. Noting that a Gaussian has a non-zero value for all real numbers, there exists no real number for which your p-value will not be zero. Even numbers below 1 or above 7. (This is the same reason that the simpler multinomial distribution I gave above has a non-zero p-value for a mean observation of 7, because its probability of observing 7 is not zero.)  But just remember that invoking the CLT is just an approximation.

Comment: This all sounds correct. But it might be incomplete. The chance of getting a mean response of $4+1/\pi$ *is* zero. So is the chance (in any practical case) of getting a mean in the interval $[4+1/\pi, 4+1/\pi+10^{-100})$. That suggests things might be subtler than your analysis seems to indicate. Interesting examples occur in the continuous setting, too. Suppose a test statistic under $H_0$ has a Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution, the critical region under any alternative will consist of parts of the tails of this distribution, and you observe the number $2$. The p-value is zero, *exactly*.

Comment: @whuber I agree that I missed subtle details about p-values and when they can possibly be zero, but I'm not sure that makes my answer incomplete. I think I address the question. Also, I stated that the CLT approximation has a non-zero p-value for all real numbers, which seems to suggest (IMO) that the same is not true for the example I gave. But if that's not clear and needs stating, then maybe I could say that explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps "incomplete" was not a good characterization, because you covered a lot of ground.  Maybe that's what got my attention: I don't think I saw a definite, clear, focused statement that summarizes your answer--one that gets to the crux of the matter and plainly reveals the issue(s). I noticed several that you brought up: understanding what a p-value is; the CLT (which I think may just be a distraction here); and approximating sampling distributions of statistics. It would be nice to see these ideas prominently highlighted and, if possible, related to each other.

Comment: Well, when looking at my answer again I agree with that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It might also be informative to modify the OP's example, just a little bit, so that it conforms more closely with the intent. Let's suppose the first population (100 responses with a mean of 2) consists solely of responses between 1 and 6. A random sample of size 90 without replacement is taken from a population of 100 responses that might or might not be this one. The test statistic will be the mean. Under the null, the mean cannot possibly exceed 6. If the mean of this sample is 7, the total of $7\times 90 = 630$ proves the population mean must be at least $6.4$: the p-value should be $0$.